# Extracting shorelines from BW aerial photos using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, remote-sensing

I'm currently trying to analyze rates of shoreline change for an estuarine reserve by extracting & vectorizing shorelines from historic aerial photos, and then comparing those to the modern shorelines.

All of the literature I've read thus far seems to rely on the use of an IR band, which I don't have access to because a large portion of my data are just BW scans of photos taken by the USDA between 1937-1980. Extracting the modern shorelines isn't an issue because I have access to IR via satellite imagery, but I'm unsure how to approach the years in which that isn't an option.

So far, I've tried Iso Cluster Unsupervised Classification in ArcMap, with mixed results mostly depending on the contrast and quality of the images themselves.

Does anyone here know of a more efficient and reliable way to extract shorelines without an IR band?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No in ArcMap, but you could try running it using CoastSat open source software:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1364815219300490?via%3Dihub
https://github.com/kvos/CoastSat

Comment: I'll look into this for next time, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Follow-up for passersby:
I ended up taking a very primitive approach to this problem.

1. File -> Export map (EDIT: Right-click layer -> "Export raster" is also acceptable)
2. Change the DPI to the largest my computer can possibly handle, make sure "Write World File" is checked. Export as tif or png.
3. Correct contrast, fillbucket large water areas, and trace shorelines in Photoshop or some other image processor
4. Put processed image back into ArcMap with georeferencing intact
5. Write a script to loop through the images and apply Iso Cluster
   Unsupervised Classification with 2 classes
6. Convert raster to polygons, then to lines, and voila.

[image]

Doing this is tedious and it loses a lot of accuracy, especially if you have some digitizing scale that you need to adhere to, since keeping track of scale is a headache outside of a GIS; I would not say it's fit for a professional setting. My purposes were not so formal, so it beat manually clicking and tracing in ArcMap (as long as you have a graphics tablet).